# Question about finding tangents on mathematica?

Tags: coding-style

How can I find the tangent at the point $(2,8)$ to the curve $y=x^2+4$ on Mathematica?

How can I show the tangent of the curve at the point and I need to mark the point where they meet with the word "FunOne"

```
f[x_] := x^2+4
p = Plot[f[x], {x, 2, 8}, PlotRange -> 50]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 4;
x0 = 2;
l[x_] := f[x0] + f'[x0] (x - x0);
Plot[{f[x], l[x]}, {x, -8, 8}, Mesh -> {{x0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-1, 15}}, 
 Epilog -> Text["FunOne", {x0, f[x0]} + {1, .1}]]
```

Comment: `Epilog -> Inset["FunOne", {x0, f[x0]}, {-1.2, Center}]`

Comment: `Epilog -> Inset["FunOne", {x0, f[x0]}, {Automatic, Top}]`